# get data for per year

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a problem with query so I have two tables : Job and Job answers,so to get number of answers of every job I do like that :

```
and ((month(a.created_at) = 10 and day(a.created_at) >= 1) 
      or (month(a.created_at) between 11 and 12) 
      or (month(a.created_at) between 1 and 8) 
      or (month(a.created_at) = 9 and day (a.created_at) <= 30))
```

Now I have another modification to do is to get a new number of answers of job by per year and between two date ( 1 september and 30 december for every year) [field : created_at] ,

```
     +----------+-------+---------+------+----- +
     | year     | job title | number of answers |
     +----------+-------+---------+------+------+
     | 2008     | Job1      | 58                | 
     | 2010     | Job2      | 45                | 
     | 2012     | Job3      | 122               |
     +----------+-------+---------+------+------
```

year and date is in created_at field...

Edit :

for 01/10 to 30/9 I do :

```
  and ( (month(a.created_at) = 10 and day(a.created_at) >= 1) 
        or month(a.created_at)   between 11 and 12 
        or month(a.created_at) between 1 and 8 
        or (month(a.created_at) = 9 and day (a.created_at) <= 30))
```

edit 2 :

```
 delimiter $$
begin

declare @StartDay INT, @EndDay INT, @StartMonth INT, @EndMonth INT
Select @StartDay = 01, @StartMonth = 10, @EndDay = 30, @EndMonth = 09

Select year(a.created_at) as years , jd.JobDomain, count(a.Id) as nb_answer,   a.Job_id,   j.JobTitle 
 from JobAppliance a
 inner join Job j on a.Job_id =  j.PublicId
 inner join JobDestination d on j.Id=d.Job_id
 inner join Jjobdomain jd on  j.Id = jd.Job_id

 and 
(
@StartMonth = @EndMonth And 
Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And 
Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay And 
Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
) Or (
@StartMonth != @EndMonth And (
(
 Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And
  Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay
) Or (
  Month(a.created_at) Between @StartMonth + 1 And @EndMonth - 1
) Or (
  Month(a.created_at) = @EndMonth And
  Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
)
)
)

group by year(a.created_at) , a.Job_id, j.JobTitle;

end$$
delimiter ;
```

I have a syntax error in declare?

Comment: Why is this tagged both `mysql` and `sql-server`?  Each platform has different capabilities...

Comment: What is the field definition for `a.created_at`? Is it a date field? Is it a timestamp? Is it a varchar?

Comment: created_at is a datetime like : 2008-10-17 10:13:58

Comment: @BlaiseSwanwick I want to get date between 1/9 and 1/12 and created_at is a datetime like : 2008-10-17 10:13:58

Comment: Laurence is on the right track with his answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should give what you want:

```
select year(a.created_at) , count(a.Id) as nb_answer, a.Job_id, j.JobTitle 
from JobAnswer a
inner join Job j on a.Job_id =  j.job_id
where month(a.created_at) between 9 and 11 Or (
  month(a.created_at) = 12 and
  day(a.created_at) = 1
)
group by year(a.created_at), a.Job_id, j.JobTitle;
```

Updated to newly specified date range

A more general solution would be to have a table with start_date, end_date for defining the ranges of interest and joining to that instead.

This might work more generally for a continuous date range within a year, but I haven't tested it. The idea is that you fill out the values of @StartDay etc that you want

```
Declare @StartDay int, @EndDay int, @StartMonth int, @EndMonth int
Select @StartDay = 30, @StartMonth = 9, @EndDay = 1, @EndMonth = 12

Select Year(a.created_at), j.JobTitle, count(a.Id) as nb_answer 
from JobAnswer a
inner join Job j on a.Job_id =  j.job_id
where (
  @StartMonth = @EndMonth And 
  Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And 
  Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay And 
  Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
) Or (
  @StartMonth != @EndMonth And (
    (
  Month(a.created_at) = @StartMonth And
      Day(a.created_at) >= @StartDay
    ) Or (
      Month(a.created_at) Between @StartMonth + 1 And @EndMonth - 1
    ) Or (
      Month(a.created_at) = @EndMonth And
      Day(a.created_at) <= @EndDay
    )
  )
)
Group By Year(a.created_at), j.JobTitle;
```

Comment: it's not to simple but created at is a datetime : 2008-10-17 10:13:58 ,also date is month and day too!

Comment: I want to get date between 1/9 and 1/12

Comment: You could mess about with the where clause. E.g. `where (month(a.created_at) = 9 and day(a.created_at) = 30) Or (month(a.created_at) = 10 and day (a.created_at) = 1)` However, you might be better creating a separate table with start date, end date of the ranges you are interested in and joining against that instead.

Comment: I cant change database is already exist but I dont guess it's a good solution?!

Comment: what you means with this and month(a.created_at) between 9 and 11 Or (
  month(a.created_at) = 12 and
  day(a.created_at) = 1
)  ,that mean date between 30/9  and 1/12

Comment: It means the date is between 1/9 and 1/12, which is the second range you posted. If you actually meant 30/9 and 1/12 then you'll need something like `(Day=30 and Month=9) Or Month between 10 and 11 or (Day=1 and Month=12)`

Comment: I dont understand you you can update ur query above with the correct query

Comment: what u will lose if you write a correct query above, I hope date between 30/9 and 1/12 so why you put "10" end "11"?

Comment: I've tried twice and you keep changing your mind about what date range you meant. You can only use month between if you want the whole month, as you want part of a month you need to look at the day and month in conjuction. In general `(Month = @StartMonth And Day >= @StartDay) Or Month Between @StartMonth + 1 and @EndMonth - 1 Or (Month = @EndMonth And Day <= @EndDay)`.

Comment: Ok Laurence,so I do with a lot of dates,you can see please my code above and tell me is correct or not?

Comment: I've updated my answer. The way to tell whether your code is correct or not is to create some sample data and try it!

Comment: ok another question please when I put your solution,mysql workbensh tell i have a syntax error in "declare" ?

Comment: This is for SQL Server, as the post is tagged.